# storing Json in global variable after an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hello I have a problem storing my json in a global variable, what I want is to do first all my ajax request then store each of the returned data to a global variable, but it seems it's not working correctly? Can Any help me to my problem? Thanks. :)

```
var series;

function columnChart(container)
{
url = base_url+"/codeigniter/index.php/AssistanceMonitoringModule/assistanceMonitoring/getSeries";

 $.ajax(
            {
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                series = data;
            },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
              }

            });

 callColumnChart(container,series);
```

}

Comment: A hint: your title already has an important keyword: "after". `callColumnChart` is called **before** the ajax request is completed

Comment: hmmm. Yeah, but I want to do all my ajax before passing the resulted data to the callColumnChart. That's why I call my callColumnChart after the ajax request.

Comment: It seems you don't understand async behavior and Ajax yet. Have a look at the duplicate question, it should help you understand the overall problem better.

Comment: aw. so i can't ready first all my data before calling a specific function? :/

Comment: Of course you can. You have to call the specific function inside the Ajax callback. The callback is called when your data is ready.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the variable too soon. The Ajax request will not be completed when you call callColumnChart. Move it into the ajax callback.

```
$.ajax(
            {
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
                series = data;
                callColumnChart(container,series);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("XHR:"+xhr.status+"Error:"+thrownError);
              }

            });
```

Comment: "The Ajax call may not be completed when you call it" --- it's not uncertain in this case. It must be: the ajax request will **NEVER** be completed

Comment: nope. It's a single threaded environment. So the callback is guaranteed to be called after that

Comment: The response can only be processed after the current execution terminates.

Comment: im nuts, I don't know what to do. :/ How can I process all the data before passing it in callColumnChart. :(

Comment: @akoDwin: By calling `callColumnChart` inside the success callback. I don't understand why this is a problem for you.